# how to stop motherboard coil whine when moving mouse on z370 or z390 chipset?

Tags: motherboard, mouse, intel-core-i7

Hi does anyone know how to stop motherboard coil whine while scrolling & generally using the mouse. Have tried z390 Asus Prime a, Aorus Pro, msi carbon pro z390 motherboards + evga z370 classified K

Comment: Coil whine doesn't usually come from the motherboard, but rather from the GPU or PSU.

Comment: Even if it did come from the motherboard it would be unique to your hardware.